# Function of handsontable only when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a function which locks my cells in handsontable but I want to lock them only when the page is loaded.

```
cells:function(row,col,prop){ //Fonctions pour bloquer les cellules
                    var cellProperties = {};

                    if ([0].indexOf(row) !== -1 && col >= 0)  
                    {
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                        cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer;
                    }

                    if(([0].indexOf(col) == 0) && (data_itk_pro_update[row][0]) && flag==true) //Here is the function to block the first column
                    {
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                    }

                    if(([1].indexOf(col) == 0) && (data_itk_pro_update[row][1]) && flag==true)
                    {
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                    }

                    if (readOnlyCellsITKPROU[[row,col]]) { 
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                    }

                    return cellProperties;
                    },
```

When the user insert data in a new row, I don't want the new cells to be blocked. So I think about a condition like :

> If the page is loading

But I don't know how to do. And I don't know the utility of `prop`.

Can someone help me please ?

**EDIT** : I tried several thing :

```
if (document.readyState === "complete")  {
```

..

```
 $(window).load(function () {
```

..

```
window.onload = function () {
```

..

```
if(window.onload){
```

**EDIT2 :**

The entire initialization of my element :

```
var container = document.getElementById('tab_itk_pro_modif');
            var hotITKPROU = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: data_itk_pro_update,
                minSpareRows: 1,
                fixedRowsTop : 1,
                rowHeaders: false,
                colHeaders: false,
                contextMenu: {
                    items: {
                        "remove_row": {
                              name: 'Supprimer la ligne',
                              disabled: function () {
                                return hotITKPROU.getSelected()[0] === 0
                              }
                         }
                    }
                },
                cells:function(row,col,prop){ //Fonctions pour bloquer les cellules

                    var cellProperties = {};

                    if ([0].indexOf(row) !== -1 && col >= 0)  //Pour bloquer la première ligne
                    {
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                        cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer;
                    }

                    if(([0].indexOf(col) == 0) && (data_itk_pro_update[row][0]) && flag==true)
                    {
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                    }

                    if(([1].indexOf(col) == 0) && (data_itk_pro_update[row][1]) && flag==true)
                    {
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                    }

                    if (readOnlyCellsITKPROU[[row,col]]) { //Pour bloquer les composants des id concaténés
                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
                    }

                    return cellProperties;
                    },
```

Comment: A stackoverflow question already exists for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Comment: @JoshSpears I looked but it's not the same application. I can't use something like that with handsontable :/

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: ```$(docuemnt).ready(function(){
//your code here
});```

Comment: @JoshSpears It can't work because it's a handsontable function in the initialization of the element. I edited for you to see that I can't use that event :/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a very basic question in JavaScript. I suggest you googling "load event js", "Javascript executes after page load", etc.

Unless you are looking for a specific way of doing it in `handsontable`, in which case it probably has to do with their hooks. For more information, [look it up in the documentation](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/Hooks.html).

Comment: i already looked in the doc, that's why I ask the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is change the `cells` definition after the page is loaded, you could always update it using

```
hotInstance.updateSettings({
    cells: newCells // where newCells is a new set of conditionals
})
```

You could trigger this inside

```
$(docuemnt).ready(function(){ // updateSettings });
```